# Multi Line AWK capture

Tags: awk

I have a requirement.
let say, below i have as input in file file1.txt

```
start
asfsafsf
faffsa
gygfyt
end1
dddadd
start
afsaf
safsaf
asdasd
start
asda
DD
end2
aasfsa
afaf
start
dada
afaf
asfs
end3
fafaf
```

I need to capture string between start & end3, then output expected as,

```
start
dada
afaf
asfs
end3
```

If i need to capture for end2, then i need output as,

```
start
asda
DD
end2
```

Can some one help me in awk command as sed is slower.

Comment: How do you know `sed` is slower if you don't know how to do it with `awk`? Just wondering :-) How big is your file, by the way? Do you know how fast `grep` will be?

Comment: why are there non-closed/non-paired start/end ? E.g. `start - start -end2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite legibly like this:

```
awk '/start/{out=$0;next} /end3/{out=out RS $0;print out;out=""}{if(length(out))out=out RS $0}' file
```

So, if we see the word `start` we set the output string to the current line and move to next line. If we have reached `end3` (you can change it to `end2`), we print the accumulated output. On all other lines, if we have started accumulating an output line, we add the current line after a linefeed character.

If you have lots of files and you want to parse them in parallel, you can use GNU Parallel, like this:

```
parallel -q awk '/start/{out=$0;next} /end3/{out=out RS $0;print out;out=""}{if(length(out))out=out RS $0}' ::: *.txt
```

Comment: Hi Mark, This command is very slow, i can not execute on *.log as i have many files. Is there anyway to make it faster ?

Comment: I have nearly 300 files having each varies from 4-7mb.

Comment: @OleTange Thank you so much for your insights & corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the input file will do the trick:

```
$ tac infile|awk '/end3/{f=1}f;/start/{f=0}'|tac
```

For multiple files use:

```
$ tac files*|awk '/end3/{f=1}f;/start/{f=0}'|tac
```

Comment: Hi Klashxx, your solution is correct, but it wont help me, as i have lots of files and i am not aware which file will have start & end3 pair. i was about to call awk command over all files, like, awk '/start/,/end3/' *.log

Comment: Hi Klashxx, Is there anway in awk to use backward search or reverse search in file from bottom to top without using tac.

Answer (score 0):

this awk oneliner does it no matter the `start - endx` paired or not

```
awk -v n="2" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=NR;if($0~"end"n){s=a["start"];e=a["end"n];nextfile}}
                      FNR>=s&&FNR<=e' file file
```

change the `-v n="2"` to a variable to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/.*(?:^|\n)(start(?:(?!start|end3).)*\nend3)(?:\n|$).*/\1\n/s' f
start
dada
afaf
asfs
end3
$ perl -0777pe 's/.*(?:^|\n)(start(?:(?!start|end2).)*\nend2)(?:\n|$).*/\1\n/s' f
start
asda
DD
end2
```